# JavaFX, leaving and entering Tab control

Tags: javafx

I have a JavaFX application. Main window consists of a TabPane (P1). P1 contains 4 different Tab controls (T11,T12,T13,T14). T11 contains a TabPane (P2) wich contains two Tab controls (T21, T22).

I am searching for a easy way to detect then any of the Tab controls gets or loses visibility. Using SelectionModel Events is not enough.

//lg

Comment: Why is using selection model events not enough? This (and/or each tab's `selectedProperty`) should give you all the information you need.

Comment: Well,,, I cant make it work. Problem is, for example, going from T12 to T11. I can detect this. But, P2 will not fire any events for T21 or T22. Of course I can detect wich of T21 or T22 that is visible and manually call a function,, but code i getting messy. I was searching for a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can observe each tab's `selectedProperty`. For T21 and T22, I think you really want to know if T21 and T11 are both selected to know if T21 is visible; for this you just observe `t11.selectedProperty().and(t21.selectedProperty())`: i.e. you can do something like

```
t11.selectedProperty().and(t21.selectedProperty()).addListener(...);
```

and provide a `ChangeListener<Boolean>`. This will be `true` if and only if both t11 and t12 are selected, and the listener will be notified if it changes from `false` to `true` or vice-versa.

Here's a complete example using FXML.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TabSelectionDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("TabSelectionDemo.fxml")), 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

TabSelectionDemo.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<TabPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="TabSelectionDemoController" fx:id="p1">
    <Tab fx:id="t11" text="T11">
        <TabPane fx:id="p2">
            <Tab fx:id="t21" text="T21">
                <Label text="This is T21"/>
            </Tab>
            <Tab fx:id="t22" text="T22">
                <Label text="This is T22"/>
            </Tab>
        </TabPane>
    </Tab>
    <Tab fx:id="t12" text="T12">
        <Label text="This is T12"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab fx:id="t13" text="T13">
        <Label text="This is T13"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab fx:id="t14" text="T14">
        <Label text="This is T14"/>
    </Tab>
</TabPane>
```

TabSelectionDemoController.java:

```
import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanBinding;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;


public class TabSelectionDemoController {
    @FXML
    private Tab t11 ;
    @FXML
    private Tab t12 ;
    @FXML
    private Tab t13 ;
    @FXML
    private Tab t14 ;
    @FXML
    private Tab t21 ;
    @FXML
    private Tab t22 ;

    private BooleanBinding t21Selected ;
    private BooleanBinding t22Selected ;

    public void initialize() {
        t11.selectedProperty().addListener(createListener("t11"));
        t12.selectedProperty().addListener(createListener("t12"));
        t13.selectedProperty().addListener(createListener("t13"));
        t14.selectedProperty().addListener(createListener("t14"));

        t21Selected = t21.selectedProperty().and(t11.selectedProperty()) ;
        t22Selected = t22.selectedProperty().and(t11.selectedProperty()) ;

        t21Selected.addListener(createListener("t21"));
        t22Selected.addListener(createListener("t22"));
    }

    private ChangeListener<Boolean> createListener(String tabName) {
        return (obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
            if (isNowSelected) {
                System.out.println(tabName + " gained visible selection");
            } else {
                System.out.println(tabName + " lost visible selection");
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: I did try this,, " t11.selectedProperty().and(t21.selectedProperty()).addListener(...);" but it never triggers for me. Have you tested your code?

Comment: Yes: it ran fine. Did you run the code above? Perhaps I am not understanding what you are trying to do. Updated to add that explicit code in the example.

Comment: You understand me fine. Diffrence between my code and yours,, is the way you create the tabs. I have used scenebuilder,, maby that makes some difference?

Comment: I suspect the question is completely unrelated to what you are doing wrong then. Create and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It works fine with FXML too (there is really no difference between the two approaches anyway). I updated the example to use FXML-created tabs instead of ones created in Java.

Comment: Okey,, now it works. I must have done something wrong before. When I coopied your code,, everything is ok. Thanks.

Comment: I did some more coding,, and suddenly the code stopped working. Started to search for the reason, and noticed that the code works differently in debug and normal mode. Also I noticed that behaviour changed depending how the code looked (i.e added and removed code). So,,, my conclusion is that it some hazard in the behaviour, cant quite understand why.

Comment: You are running into [this annoying "feature"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785816/javafx-beans-binding-suddenly-stops-working/23788155#23788155). See updated controller code for a workaround.

Comment: You might also want to look at [this blog](http://tomasmikula.github.io/blog/2015/02/10/the-trouble-with-weak-listeners.html) (see also the [subsequent post](http://tomasmikula.github.io/blog/2015/02/10/val-a-better-observablevalue.html)) for a cleaner workaround (that uses a third party library).

Comment: Tanks for your help. /lg