# Multiple, but limited, CheckBoxes in FXML/JavaFX

Tags: checkbox, javafx, listener

I'm trying to find a way to use check boxes to allow the user to pick two things from a list of three, and then have the remaining check box become disabled until one of the others is un-selected. I have a ChangeListener attached to all three check boxes, so I can register when two have been selected, but I don't know how to target the "other" box/boxes to disable/enable them.

```
ChangeListener checkboxlistener = new ChangeListener() {
int i = 0;
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {


            if((boolean) observable.getValue() == true) {

                i++;
                System.out.println(i);
            } else {
                i--;
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            if(i == 2) {
                //What should I put here, if anything?//
            }
        }

};
    checkbox1.selectedProperty().addListener(checkboxlistener);
    checkbox2.selectedProperty().addListener(checkboxlistener);
    checkbox3.selectedProperty().addListener(checkboxlistener);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep a collection of selected check boxes and unselected check boxes. Add a listener to each check box's `selectedProperty` and make sure it is in the correct collections when the selection changes.

Then you can just observe the size of the collection of selected check boxes, and update the `disable` state of all the unselected check boxes accordingly.

Here's an example:

MultipleCheckBoxExampleController.java:

```
package multiplecheckbox;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.IntegerBinding;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableSet;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;

public class MultipleCheckBoxExampleController {
    @FXML
    private CheckBox checkBox1 ;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox checkBox2 ;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox checkBox3 ;
    @FXML
    private Button submitButton ;

    private ObservableSet<CheckBox> selectedCheckBoxes = FXCollections.observableSet();
    private ObservableSet<CheckBox> unselectedCheckBoxes = FXCollections.observableSet();

    private IntegerBinding numCheckBoxesSelected = Bindings.size(selectedCheckBoxes);

    private final int maxNumSelected =  2; 

    public void initialize() {
        configureCheckBox(checkBox1);
        configureCheckBox(checkBox2);
        configureCheckBox(checkBox3);

        submitButton.setDisable(true);

        numCheckBoxesSelected.addListener((obs, oldSelectedCount, newSelectedCount) -> {
            if (newSelectedCount.intValue() >= maxNumSelected) {
                unselectedCheckBoxes.forEach(cb -> cb.setDisable(true));
                submitButton.setDisable(false);
            } else {
                unselectedCheckBoxes.forEach(cb -> cb.setDisable(false));
                submitButton.setDisable(true);
            }
        });


    }

    private void configureCheckBox(CheckBox checkBox) {

        if (checkBox.isSelected()) {
            selectedCheckBoxes.add(checkBox);
        } else {
            unselectedCheckBoxes.add(checkBox);
        }

        checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
            if (isNowSelected) {
                unselectedCheckBoxes.remove(checkBox);
                selectedCheckBoxes.add(checkBox);
            } else {
                selectedCheckBoxes.remove(checkBox);
                unselectedCheckBoxes.add(checkBox);
            }

        });

    }

}
```

MultipleCheckBoxExample.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="multiplecheckbox.MultipleCheckBoxExampleController"
     alignment="center" spacing="5">

    <padding>
        <Insets top="10" bottom="10" left="10" right="10" />
    </padding>

    <CheckBox fx:id="checkBox1" text="Choice 1" />
    <CheckBox fx:id="checkBox2" text="Choice 2" />
    <CheckBox fx:id="checkBox3" text="Choice 3" />
    <Button fx:id="submitButton" text="Submit" />
</VBox>
```

Main.java:

```
package multiplecheckbox;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            VBox root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MultipleCheckBoxExample.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test that out. Two things though,  first, if I'm using FXML, do I try to fit this snippit of code into the initialize method in the controller, or do I put it elsewhere? It seems like it would go in the main class. Second, does this mesh well with SceneBuilder? Because I've never messed with mixing UI elements created outside of SceneBuilder with those made inside of it.

Comment: You can create the check boxes in FXML and then just configure them with the handlers etc in the initialize method. I'll update the example when I'm back at the computer.

Comment: Also, upon copying that to Netbeans (into the main class of a new FXML project), it runs and gives me three check boxes, but allows me to select all three

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know if you're a DnD guy, but I'm trying to learn this trick so that I can accurately limit the number of Feats a player can pick at character creation, maybe I could even repurpose it into an equipment weight tracker for an inventory.

Comment: Updated example to use FXML: it's pretty much the same as before. I tested it and it works fine.

Comment: There must be something I'm missing here, or something wrong with my IDE, because I just copied all three examples into my NetBeans, and while it loads and shows me the check boxes, I can still select all three after  I run the project.

Comment: I think you are running into the [premature binding garbage collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785816/javafx-beans-binding-suddenly-stops-working/23788155#23788155) issue. I changed the code so it should avoid this.

Comment: You sir are a scholar and a saint. You can bet that as soon as I get my RPG functional that there'll be a "Benevolent King James" somewhere in there, seriously, I owe you a virtual beer. Could you tell me what in particular you modified in order to avoid that garbage collection issue? I'm reading through your code and digesting how it works and I want to make sure I'm aware of how that workaround works.

Comment: To prevent garbage collection of the binding, I just created an explicit reference to the result of calling `Bindings.size()` (`numCheckBoxesSelected`). This ensures the binding cannot be garbage collected as long as the controller instance remains in scope. In the [previous version](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30546246/revisions) the binding was only created locally in the `initialize()` method, so it went out of scope at the end of that method invocation. Since `Bindings` use weak listeners, the binding can be garbage collected event though the list references the listener.

Comment: Also, please feel free to mark the answer as correct (click on the check mark) if it answers the question. This will help other users find it.