# JavaFX: Button jumps off the binding with SplitPane.Divider

Tags: java, binding, javafx, splitpane

I have `SplitPane` with two `AnchorPane` (left and right side). There are `Label`, `TextField` and `Button` on each `AnchorPane`, they are arranged in one line. `Label` must bind to the left side `AnchorPane`, `Button` to the right and `TextField` must be stretched between them. Left `AnchorPane` must be bind to left part of `SplitPane`.

My code works, but when I move divider after some time `Buttons` jump off the binding with `SplitPane`.
`AnchorPane` width bind to `SplitPane.Divider`, `Label`, `TextField`, `Button` bind to `AnchorPane`.
Can you help me?
Sorry for my English.

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.beans.binding.DoubleBinding;
    import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
    import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class Main extends Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Application.launch(args);
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) {
            stage.setTitle("BackUpManager");
            AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800,600);

            SplitPane splitPane = new SplitPane();
            splitPane.setLayoutY(50);
            splitPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty());
            splitPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(root.heightProperty().subtract(50));

            AnchorPane rRoot = new AnchorPane();
            AnchorPane wRoot = new AnchorPane();

            splitPane.getItems().addAll(rRoot,wRoot);

            rRoot.setMinWidth(200);
            rRoot.prefWidthProperty().bind(splitPane.getDividers().get(0).positionProperty());
            Button rBrowse = new Button();
            rRoot.getChildren().add(rBrowse);
            rBrowse.setText("Browse");
            DoubleBinding db0 = rRoot.widthProperty().subtract(55);
            db0.addListener(new javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener<Number>() {
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number t, Number t1) {
                    rBrowse.setLayoutX(db0.getValue());
                }});
            Label rLabel = new Label("Reserve dir");
            rRoot.getChildren().add(rLabel);
            rLabel.setLayoutY(3);
            TextField rPath = new TextField();
            rRoot.getChildren().add(rPath);
            rPath.setLayoutX(60);
            rPath.prefWidthProperty().bind(rRoot.widthProperty().subtract(115));        

            wRoot.prefWidthProperty().bind(splitPane.widthProperty().subtract(splitPane.getDividers().get(0).positionProperty()));
            wRoot.setMinWidth(200);
            Button wBrowse = new Button();
            wRoot.getChildren().add(wBrowse);
            wBrowse.setText("Browse");
            DoubleBinding db1 = wRoot.widthProperty().subtract(55);
            db1.addListener(new javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener<Number>() {
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number t, Number t1) {
                    wBrowse.setLayoutX(db1.getValue());
                }});
            Label wLabel = new Label("Working dir");
            wRoot.getChildren().add(wLabel);
            wLabel.setLayoutY(3);
            TextField wPath = new TextField();
            wRoot.getChildren().add(wPath);
            wPath.setLayoutX(64);
            wPath.prefWidthProperty().bind(wRoot.widthProperty().subtract(119));

            rBrowse.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle (ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Called");
                }
            });

            root.getChildren().addAll(splitPane);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Example:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/j7xz40fzwbbh2fy/AAA9mmm2msgBAh9PbKlmKn4Va?dl=0

Comment: Why don't you place the Label, TextField and Button inside a HBox and then add it to the AnchorPane? This would save you a lot of effort on bindings.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and write here about results.

Comment: Thank you! This works well with Hbox.

Comment: You are probably running into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785816/javafx-beans-binding-suddenly-stops-working/23788155#23788155 Using an appropriate layout instead of trying to bind everything should fix things. You can set the anchors on the split pane (e.g. `AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(splitPane, 0.0);` etc) too, instead of binding the split pane's width etc.