# Java Bindings: BindBidirectional not work

Tags: java, binding, javafx, jvm

**UPDATED**

My problem is that the bi-directional binding (`bindBidirectional`) not works.

I found a way to reproduce the behavior with the following code:

This is the FXML:

```
<VBox spacing="5.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/null" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.test.MyTestPaneView">
   <children>
      <Label text="This is a Test Pane" />
      <ScrollPane fitToWidth="true">
         <content>
            <FlowPane fx:id="pnl" />
         </content>
      </ScrollPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

This is the controller class:

```
public class MyTestPaneView implements Initializable{
    private static final int MAX = 1000;
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    @FXML
    private FlowPane pnl;

    private final BooleanProperty[] modelArray = new BooleanProperty[MAX];
    private final Node[] viewArray = new Node[MAX];

    private final ToggleGroup rbGrp = new ToggleGroup(), btnGrp = new ToggleGroup();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        for (int i=0; i<MAX; i++) {
            final int index = i;

            modelArray[i] = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
            modelArray[i].addListener(observable -> System.out.println("Model Update: " + index));

            switch (Math.abs(RANDOM.nextInt() % 3)) {
                case 0:
                    final CheckBox ckb = new CheckBox("CKB " + i);
                    ckb.selectedProperty().addListener(observable -> System.out.println("View Update: " + index));
                    ckb.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(modelArray[i]);
                    viewArray[i] = ckb;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    final RadioButton rb = new RadioButton("RB " + i);
                    rb.setToggleGroup(rbGrp);
                    rb.selectedProperty().addListener(observable -> System.out.println("View Update: " + index));
                    rb.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(modelArray[i]);
                    viewArray[i] = rb;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    final ToggleButton btn = new ToggleButton("BTN " + i);
                    btn.setToggleGroup(btnGrp);
                    btn.selectedProperty().addListener(observable -> System.out.println("View Update: " + index));
                    btn.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(modelArray[i]);
                    viewArray[i] = btn;
                    break;
            }

            pnl.getChildren().add(viewArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the basic pane:

```
public class MyTestPane extends BorderPane {

    public MyTestPane() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("org/test/MyTestPaneView.fxml"));
            loader.setControllerFactory(cl -> new MyTestPaneView());
            final Pane pane = loader.load();

            setCenter(pane);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Code to run:

```
public class Runner extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setScene(new Scene(new MyTestPane(), 1280, 1024));
    stage.show();
  }
}
```

Expected behavior is that each click on any component produces 2 output lines: one for the UI change and one for the background model change:

```
View Update: 127
Model Update: 127
View Update: 405
Model Update: 405
```

In some cases it shows so:

```
View Update: 5
Model Update: 5
View Update: 233
View Update: 509
View Update: 12
Model Update: 12
```

If you copy it into a project and run it you will notice that the first part of buttons and checkboxes work correctly and the last part not. How many nodes not work correctly differs from execution to execution.

The core of this code is the bidirectional binding that not work correctly.

Is it a bug in JVM? I run it with Java 1.8 U60 / U66 (x64) and Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Please create a [MCVE]. It's impossible to tell if this is a bug in your code or in the library code from the tiny snippet you posted.

Comment: For what it's worth I created the smallest compilable example I could including exactly your code, and both messages were displayed, so I strongly suspect it is your code (that you haven't shown) that is the issue.

Comment: This is an example. I am not be able to rebuild a code with same behavior because this behavior is not easy to reproducible.

Comment: Well, it's not really an "example" unless it reproduces the behavior you say you see. If you can't create code to reproduce it, there's really no question for anyone to answer.

Comment: **I have updated the example**

Comment: It would *really* be helpful if you could package this as an actual [MCVE] that I could copy, paste, and run (with an actual main class, etc). Is it really necessary to use FXML and a custom subclass of `BorderPane` to reproduce the issue? (If so, you should say so in your question.) I just spent 10-15 minutes making this into something I could run, and then it worked just fine.

Comment: The code above is an complete example. I am not be able to post more or more complex code cause this is part of company code. But the code above you can copied in a project.

Comment: Please note: This is an example. The company code is very, very complex with many of FXML files. The using of `BorderPane` inside is not required to rebuild this behavior.

Comment: Seriously, if you want help, please just create a new example from scratch that **runs** and reproduces the problem. That way you don't copy any proprietary code, and by copying code you have tested you avoid stupid mistakes (like omitting `static` from your main method) which other people have to fix for you. Make it *minimal* (so if you don't need an inheritance hierarchy to reproduce the problem, don't use one). Include imports where needed so no-one has to waste their time figuring out where the FXML belongs (do you really need FXML to reproduce this???).

Comment: With this example code above I can reproduce the behavior on my machine.

Comment: Technically, unless you fix the `public void main(...)` error, you can't reproduce anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically a duplicate of [JavaFX Beans Binding suddenly stops working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785816/javafx-beans-binding-suddenly-stops-working) Your bindings are getting garbage collected because you don't retain a reference to anything that uses them.

In most cases in "real" code (i.e. not example code) you retain references to your model, as it will be shared among different components in the UI, so this is not an issue.

You can for the problem to be reproduced by forcing garbage collection:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class MyTestPane extends BorderPane {

    public MyTestPane() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
//            loader.setLocation(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("MyTestPaneView.fxml"));
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("MyTestPaneView.fxml"));
            loader.setControllerFactory(cl -> new MyTestPaneView());
            final Pane pane = loader.load();

            setCenter(pane);

            Button gc = new Button("GC");
            gc.setOnAction(e -> System.gc());
            setBottom(gc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

In this version, once you press the "GC" button, all model updates will stop.

You can fix the problem here by retaining a reference to the controller in your custom control class:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class MyTestPane extends BorderPane {

    private MyTestPaneView controller ;

    public MyTestPane() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
//            loader.setLocation(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("MyTestPaneView.fxml"));
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("MyTestPaneView.fxml"));
            loader.setControllerFactory(cl -> new MyTestPaneView());
            final Pane pane = loader.load();

            controller = loader.getController();

            setCenter(pane);

            Button gc = new Button("GC");
            gc.setOnAction(e -> System.gc());
            setBottom(gc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously the exact details of how you force those references to be retained may vary in your actual code, but this should give you enough to fix the problem.

You might also be interested in http://tomasmikula.github.io/blog/2015/02/10/the-trouble-with-weak-listeners.html

Comment: Added code that forces garbage collection, demonstrating that really is the issue.

Comment: I think this is a very big bug. The controller must be safe for GC while the pane is showed and instantiated. That is a case for the FXML framework, I thing. It shows like controller will be used ago after call of controller factory.

Comment: Well, you can file it as a bug, but it is deliberate, and as such will likely not be fixed. The problem is that without using weak listeners, in many cases (particularly with virtualized controls such as `ListView` etc), bindings will create memory leaks without a lot of very complex code to release the binding. See Tomas Mikula's blog (linked in updated answer) for more discussion and an alternative approach.

Comment: Also, caching the controller here is really just a mechanism to cache the *model*. The thing you really need to retain references to is the array of `BooleanProperty`. In real life, the application structure is usually to implement the model as some kind of singleton (e.g. with a DI framework) and then pass a reference to it to each controller/presenter that needs to access it. In that application structure you naturally preserve strong references to anything that is bound.

Comment: But in this case I never can use `FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(...))` method in JavaFX framework cause I never get the controller.

Comment: The static `FXMLLoader.load()` method is an ugly travesty that should never have made it to the API anyway... :). (I think there have been some suggestions to deprecate it.) In any real application, you will pretty much always find you need to configure the controller *somehow* (either initialize it with a model, or set a controller factory to use DI in the controllers), so you rarely use it in production code. Again, at some point you create the model, if you keep a reference to that, all will be well.