# JavaFX: Bind to nested position

Tags: javafx, binding, position

I have a `Pane` that contains some `VBox`s and `Line`s. I want to bind the endpoints of the `Line`s to the "anchors" inside the `VBox`s (basically I want to bind to the position of a `Node` nested arbitrarily deep in the `VBox`), but I can't figure out what value represents the `Node`s position relative to the top `Pane`. I've tried layout properties, translate properties, as well as bounds in local and bounds in parent, and none of them seem to work. What am I missing?

(I can provide a code sample if needed, but I don't think it helps explain my problem any better since I can't get it to work.)

EDIT: I forgot to mention the `VBox` can be moved around the pane freely, which is why I need to bind the lines.

EDIT: Here's some source showing my progress. I can get the correct location, but it's not binding

```
public class Graph extends Application {
    private double startX;
    private double startY;

    private ObjectBinding<Bounds> bounds;
    private DoubleBinding tx;
    private DoubleBinding ty;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        Circle target = new Circle(5, Color.RED);
        VBox node = wrap(target);
        Line connector = new Line();
        bounds = Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
                    Bounds nodeLocal = target.getBoundsInLocal();
                    Bounds nodeScene = target.localToScene(nodeLocal);
                    Bounds nodePane = pane.sceneToLocal(nodeScene);
                    return nodePane;
                },
                target.boundsInLocalProperty(),
                target.localToSceneTransformProperty(),
                pane.localToSceneTransformProperty()
        );
        connector.setStartX(0);
        connector.setStartY(0);
        tx = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> bounds.get().getMinX(), bounds);
        ty = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> bounds.get().getMinY(), bounds);
        connector.endXProperty().bind(tx);
        connector.endYProperty().bind(ty);
        connector.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        pane.getChildren().add(node);
        pane.getChildren().add(connector);
        node.relocate(100, 100);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 300, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private VBox wrap(Circle target) {
        VBox node = new VBox(new Label("Node"), new StackPane(new Rectangle(50, 50, Color.GRAY), target));
        node.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            Node source = (Node) event.getSource();
            startX = source.getBoundsInParent().getMinX() - event.getScreenX();
            startY = source.getBoundsInParent().getMinY() - event.getScreenY();
        });
        node.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            Node source = (Node) event.getSource();
            double offsetX = event.getScreenX() + startX;
            double offsetY = event.getScreenY() + startY;
            source.relocate(offsetX, offsetY);
        });
        return node;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any `Node node` in a (meaning it has a parent or indirect ancestor) `Pane pane`, the basic idea is to do

```
ObjectBinding<Bounds> boundsInPaneBinding = Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
        Bounds nodeLocal = node.getBoundsInLocal();
        Bounds nodeScene = node.localToScene(nodeLocal);
        Bounds nodePane = pane.sceneToLocal(nodeScene);
        return nodePane ;
    }, node.boundsInLocalProperty(), node.localToSceneTransformProperty(), 
       pane.localToSceneTransformProperty());
```

Then `boundsInPaneBinding` is an `ObservableValue<Bounds>` that always contains the bounds of the `Node` in the `Pane`'s coordinate system. So you can then do things like

```
line.startXProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
    () -> boundsInPaneBinding.get().getMinX(), 
    boundsInPaneBinding));
```

The tricky part here is making sure that the bindings don't get garbage collected prematurely. (See [here](http://tomasmikula.github.io/blog/2015/02/10/the-trouble-with-weak-listeners.html) for a discussion.) First, you need to retain a reference to the binding:

```
private ObjectBinding<Bounds> boundsInPaneBinding ;
```

and then (for reasons I can't quite figure out), the binding must actually evaluate the bound property directly:

```
boundsInPaneBinding = Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
        Bounds nodeLocal = node.getBoundsInLocal();
        // note how this actually gets the value of localToSceneTransformProperty():
        Bounds nodeScene = node.getLocalToSceneTransform().apply(nodeLocal);
        Bounds nodePane = pane.sceneToLocal(nodeScene);
        return nodePane ;
    }, node.boundsInLocalProperty(), node.localToSceneTransformProperty(), 
       pane.localToSceneTransformProperty());
```

Comment: It almost does what I want. The lines end up in the right place, but they don't stay bound. I think I know what the problem may be though.

Comment: Never mind. It didn't work. I'm trying to bind to the position of a `Node` in the `VBox`, not the `VBox` itself.

Comment: @RuckusT-Boom You can use exactly the same technique, just replace the vbox with the node of interest in the code above. (Answer edited to reflect this.) The issue with them not remaining bound is probably [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785816/javafx-beans-binding-suddenly-stops-working): just make sure you keep a reference to the bindings.

Comment: It's still not working for me. Let me mess around with it a bit and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I added an example to my post that shows my issue. Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @RuckusT-Boom Updated answer. For reasons I can't quite see, you need to evaluate the `localToSceneTransformProperty()` in order to get the binding to fire.

Comment: Im not sure why but I cant to the apply part