# How to bind multiple properties to one observable in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, bind

**Update 3: solution**

I finally got it: just save a reference of **MyRoot** in a property:

**MainApp**

```
package my.group.javafxtestbinding;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {

    private MyRoot root;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        root = new MyRoot();
        HBox parent = root.myRoot;
        Scene scene = new Scene(parent, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        Button gcButton = new Button("Collect Garbage");
        gcButton.setOnMousePressed(event -> System.gc());
        parent.getChildren().add(gcButton);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Update 3 solution end**

**Update 2:**

So, I'm still having problems with losing my bindings and it's due to garbage collection; that I can reproduce. See the follwing Minimal Working Example.

The structure of the example is somewhat special, that is because I use the MVP framework from Adam Bien: [afterburner.fx](http://afterburner.adam-bien.com/). And I wanted to simulate the same structure in my example.

I read a lot (i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785816/javafx-beans-binding-suddenly-stops-working), [here](https://tomasmikula.github.io/blog/2015/02/10/the-trouble-with-weak-listeners.html)) and understand the basic problem but still can't really grasp it.
I'm somewhat new to JavaFX, hope somebody can give me a hint.

Reproduce:
When you click on an item in the table, the content of the label changes due to the binding between the selected model in the table (**Select**) and the label (**Show**). **MyRoot** manages both.
When you click on the button garbage collection is executed and the binding is gone.

**MainApp**

```
package my.group.javafxtestbinding;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        MyRoot root = new MyRoot();
        HBox parent = root.myRoot;
        Scene scene = new Scene(parent, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        Button gcButton = new Button("Collect Garbage");
        gcButton.setOnMousePressed(event -> System.gc());
        parent.getChildren().add(gcButton);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**MyRoot**

```
package my.group.javafxtestbinding;

import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

public class MyRoot {

    public HBox myRoot;
    private final Select select;
    private final Show show;

    public MyRoot() {
        select = new Select();
        show = new Show();
        myRoot = new HBox();
        myRoot.getChildren().addAll(select.myTable, show.myLabel);

        show.selectedModelProperty().bind(select.selectedModelProperty());
    }
}
```

**Select**

```
package my.group.javafxtestbinding;

import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

public class Select {
    private ObjectProperty<MyModel> selectedModel;
    public TableView<MyModel> myTable;
    private final TableColumn<MyModel, String> myColumn;

    public Select() {
        this.selectedModel = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        myTable = new TableView();
        myColumn = new TableColumn("Name");
        myTable.getColumns().add(myColumn);

        myTable.setItems(getList());
        myColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getNameProperty());

        ChangeListener<MyModel> changeListener = new ChangeListener<MyModel>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends MyModel> observable, MyModel oldValue, MyModel newValue) {
                selectedModel.set(newValue);
            }
        };
        myTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(changeListener);
    }

    public ObjectProperty<MyModel> selectedModelProperty() {
        return selectedModel;
    }

    private ObservableList<MyModel> getList() {
      MyModel model1 = new MyModel("Joe");
      MyModel model2 = new MyModel("Jim");
      MyModel model3 = new MyModel("Jack");
      ObservableList<MyModel> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(model1, model2, model3);
      return list;
  }
}
```

**Show**

```
package my.group.javafxtestbinding;

import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class Show {
    private ObjectProperty<MyModel> selectedModel;
    public Label myLabel;

    public Show() {
        this.selectedModel = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        myLabel = new Label("Init");

        ChangeListener listener = new ChangeListener<MyModel>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends MyModel> observable, MyModel oldValue, MyModel newValue) {
                if (newValue != null) {
                    myLabel.setText(newValue.getName());
                }
            }
        };
        this.selectedModel.addListener(listener);
    }

    public ObjectProperty<MyModel> selectedModelProperty() {
        return selectedModel;
    }
}
```

**MyModel**

```
package my.group.javafxtestbinding;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class MyModel {
    private final StringProperty name;

    public MyModel(String name) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public StringProperty getNameProperty() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**Update 2 end**

**Update 1:**

Ok, thank you for your comments.

I thought I was doing it wrong. But if you say that this is the correct way then the problem must be somewhere else. I will post it when I find the problem...

**Update 1 end**

**Original Post:**

I have problems binding many properties to one observable.

Let's say I have three (or more) properties `ObjectProperty<Foo> firstProp` in `FirstObject`, `ObjectProperty<Foo> secondProp` in `SecondObject` and `ObjectProperty<Foo> thirdProp` in `ThirdObject`.

How can I bind second and third property to the first which is the observable.
So when firstProp changes the ChangeListeners attached to secondProp and thirdProp will be fired.

What I tried:

```
SecondObject.secondProperty().bind(FirstObject.firstProperty());
ThirdObject.thirdProperty().bind(FirstObject.firstProperty());
```

The result is that it sometimes works and sometimes not. If I add more bindings in the same way they do not work at all.

Is this not working because of this:

> Note that JavaFX has all the bind calls implemented through weak listeners. This means the bound property can be garbage collected and stopped from being updated.
>   [Javadoc bind()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/Property.html#bind-javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue-)

I find a lot of answers to how to bind many observables to one property, but not the other way.
Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you're doing should work. Can you please [edit] your question to add a [mre] demonstrating the issue?

Comment: Garbage collection can only becomes an issue, if one of the 3 objects doesn't have a strong reference to them. Binding may fail, if you introduce a circular binding. As mentioned by Slaw we need a [mcve] to determine the actual problem in your case...

Comment: I updated my post with an example. Thank you!

Comment: I finally found the right way to do it. Updated my post with the solution. Thanks!